# How can I disable case-insensitive tab completion in zsh?

Tags: zsh

If I have a `Music` folder and a `monitor.sh` script, I want `$ ./m\t` to autocomplete to `monitor.sh`, but it's also listing the `Music` folder as a suggestion.  How can I disable this 'feature'?

I have `CASE_SENSITIVE` commented out in `.zshrc`.  I am using `oh-my-zsh` with the robbyrussell theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that backwards. You need to ***uncomment*** that line to make it case-sensitive.

Before: `./m` <kbd>Tab</kbd> matches both `monitor.sh` and `Music`

```
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"
```

After: `./m` <kbd>Tab</kbd> matches only `monitor.sh`

```
CASE_SENSITIVE="true"
```

Note: if you have **no case-sensitive matches**, then it will try the other case. I have not found a way to disable that. But as long as there is at least one matching completion it will respect the case that you typed in.

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I disable this case-sensitive 'feature'?

1. Edit your `~/.zshrc` configuration file.
2. Find the line:

   ```
   CASE_SENSITIVE="true"
   ```
3. Comment it out:

   ```
   #CASE_SENSITIVE="true"
   ```
4. Restart your shell.

Comment: It's commented out already.  I neglected to add important details so I've included those above.

Comment: "I am using oh-my-zsh with the robbyrussell theme." Well that is how it is configured in [My ZSH config (with Oh-my-ZSH) · GitHub](https://gist.github.com/romaricdrigon/fc7a697fc014dc88574f7e59ee3dacaf). Check your other startup files [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/) and make sure nothing is overriding it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I couldn't find a way, I usually have to get past the non-shared part of the name (in your case ./mo\t) it's annoying but from what I can tell there isn't a way to do what you need.

You could write a plugin ;)